# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() in php oop

Tags: php, oop, prepared-statement

Now I learn to create PHP crud operations using OOP concept

In this code I faced some issues

### Config.php

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $dbHost     = "localhost";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "";
    private $dbName     = "xtratuition";
    public $db;
    
    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbName, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
                $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->db = $conn;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $e->getMessage());
            }
            return $this->db;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

### Modules.php

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

class CrudController extends Database{
    function sqlSelect($TblName , $Condition){
        try{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `xtratuition`.$TblName WHERE $Condition";
            $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $result->execute();
            $data = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
class LoginController extends CrudController{
    public $emailID;
    function __construct($email){
        $this->emailID = $email;
    }
    function userLogin(){
        $data = $this->sqlSelect("users" , "email = '".$this->emailID."'");
        return $data;
    }
}

// This is works well

// $login = new CrudController();
// $data = $login->sqlSelect("`users`" , "email = 'klakshmanan48@gmail.com'");
// print_r($data);


$login = new LoginController("klakshmanan48@gmail.com");
$data = $login->userLogin();
print_r($data);


?>
```

I think I make a mistake in this code.
And I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

on this line

> $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are defining constructor in child class, you have to call parent constructors explicitly they wont called automatically.

You have to call parent construct in your LoginContoller class

```
class LoginController extends CrudController{
    public $emailID;
    function __construct($email){
        $this->emailID = $email;
        parent::__construct(); //explicit call to parent constructor
    }
    function userLogin(){
        $data = $this->sqlSelect("users" , "email = '".$this->emailID."'");
        return $data;
    }
}
```